# How to repeat the string in C++?

Tags: c++

I have to write a program in which integer value is entered from user and the string has to be displayed that many times. But I am getting errors.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;

    cout << "Enter N: ";
    cin  >> N;

    cout << string(N, "Well Done");

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

**Note:** I am not permitted to use a loop in this assignment.

Comment: What do you believe `string(N, "Well Done");` should actually do? There's no such consttuctoe for `std::string`. Simply use a loop.

Comment: Print Well Done N times

Comment: Where did you define `string` to do that?

Comment: The constructor you are thinking of constructs a string with `N` times *a single character*. For example, `std::string(3,'a')` is a string equivalent to `"aaa"`. It only works with characters, not string literals.

Comment: so how do I fix the code using N times?

Comment: "How to repeat the string.." - Use a loop. Print the string any number of times you want - `N` times seems to be what you want, so go with that. A simple `for` loop should do.

Comment: It has to be without using any kind of loop..and I don't know other than loop

Comment: "It has to be without using any kind of loop" - now that's just silly/stupid. You want to do `foo` `N` times, the natural thing is to write a loop. To require anything else is just putting arbitrary and silly restrictions on the solution.

Comment: is recursion allowed?

Comment: @JesperJuhl : I know that's the challenge given in the assignment.

Comment: @MPops : Sorry, I don't know what recursion is

Comment: @user7377353 also you should definitely put that restriction in the question itself. This is the most trivial thing to do in any programming language, and if a fundamental feature of that language is banned in your assignment, we should know. Any other restrictions?

Comment: @user7377353 OK. If we go out of the realm of sanity, would a solution involving labels and `goto` be ok? How about `setjmp`/`longjmp`? Is recursion OK? What about just unrolling the loop and doing `foo` `N` times in serial?

Comment: @MPops: No other restrictions.

Comment: @user7377353 _"It has to be without using any kind of loop..and I don't know other than loop"_ That's an extremely silly and unrealistic requirement. Are you playing _code golf_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Sorry, but that's the requirement...that's the challenge given to us.

Comment: @user7377353 _"I don't know what recursion is"_ I'm thinking this assignment/task was given to you as part of learning recursion.. Did your instructor seriously not give you any notes or anything? Or did you miss a class? Either way this question is hard to answer without the context of your course.

Comment: Is there any bound on how big `N` can get? I mean a crazy answer is if (N < 2) cout "Well Done"; if (N < 3) cout "Well Done"; if (N < 4) "Well Done";  ...

Comment: @user7377353 If you can't use a loop, and you don't know what recursion is, then what CAN you use? What is the ACTUAL assignment? Can you [edit] your question to provide that? I'm voting to close this question as "too broad" without that clarity.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> s(N); std::fill_n(s.begin(), N, "Well Done");`  No loops.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: - The assignment is to print Well Done as many times the user input without using loop

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie or you could use a `std::ostream_iterator` instead of wasting memory filling a `std::vector`, eg: `std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator(std::cout, " "), N, "Well Done");`

Comment: From the accepted answer, it seems the question should be reworded to use `goto`.  If this is what this question boils down to, then I pity whoever is in this class giving an assignment like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you may not use a loop, you may use `goto` to get around the restriction:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int N;

  cout << "Enter N: ";
  cin  >> N;

  {
    int i = 0;
    goto test;
    begin:
    cout << "Well Done";
    ++i;
    test:
    if (i < N)
      goto begin;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that `goto` is widely considered bad practice.

Comment: Ayxan : Your solution is accepted in assignment. Thank you!

Comment: Goto is quite unrecommended way to do that

Comment: @BorisSokolov the restriction is quite unrealistic anyway. In real code you'd use a loop, and with the given restriction, `goto` is honestly the cleanest way to achieve the goal (considering the size of the code)

Comment: @Ayxan, yes. We don't know the purpose of the lab :)

Comment: @user7377353 The thing is that this type of answer could be used for any question that says "I can't use a loop".  It would just take patience and a whole lot of free time to waste to come up with solutions using `goto`.  So what are you really learning from this, except to come with spaghetti code to solve problems that are solvable using the proper looping idioms?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I will keep this in mind.

Comment: Don't look now, but this literally *is* a loop.

Comment: @CodyGray apparently this is enough to trick whatever automatic checking system OP's instructor is using :-)

Comment: I would consider this a loop..

Answer (score 3):

EDIT2: IN THE ORIGINAL ASKER's COMMENTS, LOOPS OF ANY KIND ARE PROHIBITED IN THIS ASSIGNMENT.

Use recursion.

```
void printN(int n, string s) {
    if (n <= 0) return;
    cout << s << endl;
    printN(n-1, s);
}
```

Then you can call this from your main program as follows:

```
printN(userInput, "Hi my name is ricky bobby");
```

EDIT: just saw you haven't learned recursion yet. Look up this term, and familiarize yourself with it. This is a way to do iteration without looping (this is the most simplistic way I can describe it)

Comment: Recursion is overkill for this task, when a simple loop will suffice.

Comment: @RemyLebeau please read the original askers comment, as they very clearly state that loops are prohibited in his school project.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Except that OP said in the comments that loops are not allowed. Yeah, go figure...

Answer (score -1):

`std::string` does not have a constructor that repeats a string N times (it does have one for repeating a single character N times, though).  What you need is a loop instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;

    cout << "Enter N: ";
    cin  >> N;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cout << "Well Done";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ORIGINAL asker said that LOOPS are not allowed. This does not solve their problem.

Comment: I posted this answer before seeing the comment about that restriction. I answered the ACTUAL QUESTION that was asked, as per StackOverflow's guidelines. Such restrictions were not included in the question.

Comment: Yup, this is the more correct way to do it without restrictions.