# char array reverse lookup using no loops

Tags: c++

I have a string = "ABCD", so string[2] would return 'C'
How about if i have 'C' and I want to look up the position of C in the string?

could it be a function that returns the position of the letter given, such as

int lookup(string a)

and in this case it should return 2?

I understand I can use a for loop to look it up, as shown in my code. My problem is my homework requires me to look it up without using any "loop" hence the for loop or while or do while won't suffice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const char digits[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };

int lookup(string a, char b);

int main()
{
    string str = "ABCD";

    cout << lookup(str, 'D') << endl;
    return 0;
}

int lookup(string a, char b)
{
    // look up algorithm there
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; i++)
    {
        if ( a[i] == b)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

My example code is fine, but I need an alternative to look up the value without a loop. Is it possible?

Comment: [Some silly requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281816/how-to-repeat-the-string-in-c) again :P

Comment: If `str` stays the same, and `b` is always in `str`, then you can just `return b - 'A'`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

So the whole lookup function can be replaced by this one line:

```
return a.find(b);
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: `find` uses a loop.